# Dynamic Polymorphism : Doubt

Tags: c#, oop, visual-studio-2010

I have this code:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Testing_Class
    {
        public string A()
        {
            int i = 3;
            Console.Write("Value if i" + i);
            string a = "John";
            return a;
        }


    }

    public class Testing : Testing_Class
    {
        public string A()
        {
            string a = "John";
            Console.Write(a);
            return a;
        }

    }



    public class Test
    {
        public void foo()
        {
            Testing MyTesting = new Testing();
            MyTesting.A(); //Dynamic Polymorphism ??

        }
    }

    }
```

When I am calling MyTesting.A() is this a Dynamic Polymorphism? I have not included any `Virtual` Keyword or any `Override` here?

Your inputs?

Comment: Check your compiler output - you will have a warning.

Comment: What to hell is "Dynamic Polymorphism"? Changing the concrete implementation at runtime or what?

Comment: I did build my solution and it succeeded. I cannot run the application coz I dont have any executable project as the startup project in my solution file.

Comment: @klm9971 I did not say error, I said warning.

Comment: Even if you don't know the answer you can run the code and see what happens.

Comment: It will run and will execute the function from Class Test! This is Over Hiding property in C#.

Comment: @klm9971 If you wish to reply to a comment from another user, include their @username and they will get notified.

Comment: @Chibacity: Try to make a C# Lib project in your VS2010 and then try this code. I am trying in mine...

Comment: @klm9971: Your code is perfectly legal, but if you check your Errors window, you will see a compiler *warning* (not error) telling you that you're creating a new member with the same name (unless you have warnings hidden, of course). It's a warning because you're allowed to do it and it will run, but the compiler thinks that probably isn't what you're *trying* to do.

Comment: @klm9971 Honestly I don't have to try, you will get a compiler warning as you are hiding an inherited member without using the 'new' keyword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, there's no polymorphism going on here. You've got a non-virtual call to a non-virtual method. Unlike some other languages, methods and properties in C# are non-virtual by default.

In order to demonstrate polymorphism really working, you'd want to:

- Declare the method virtual in the base class
- Use the override modifier in the derived class
- Use a variable with a *compile-time* type of the base class for the invocation, but having initialized it with an object of the derived type.

Here's a short but complete program demonstrating all that:

```
using System;

class Base
{
    public virtual void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base.Foo");
    }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public override void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived.Foo");
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Base x = new Derived();
        x.Foo(); // Prints Derived.Foo
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not polymorphism. You're creating a new member with the same name on the subclass, *not* overriding the parent class' member. If you were to refer to your instance as an instance of the parent class, it would actually call the parent class' member, not the child class. Try it out:

```
        Testing_Class MyTesting = new Testing();
        MyTesting.A();
```

Comment: Yep! I agree to that Adam. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are not overriding but hiding. Since you did not mark the method.

That is you can hide virtual methods, but you cannot override normally derived methods.

```
        class TestBase
        {
            public void GoForIt() {}
        }

        class Test : TestBase
        {
            public virtual new void GoForIt() {}
        }


        class Other : Test
        {
            public override void GoForIt() {}
            public new void GoForIt() {}
        }
```

if you 'forget' the `new` keyword, the compiler will warn you:

> The keyword new is required on
>   "Other.GoForIt()" because it hides
>   inherited member

Comment: I think you are right. It is Overhiding the function. Overriding means you can pass different parameters.

Comment: @klm9971: No, *overloading* means providing different signatures, and there's no such term as "overhiding".

Comment: @klm: Just hiding, not Overhiding. *Overloading* is allowing different signatures (in other words, different parameters), *Overriding* is creating a function or member whose implementation can be overridden by inheriting classes.

Comment: @klm9971 `overhiding` - nice one. :)

Comment: @klm9971 Hang on let me just get Anders and Eric up on Skype, maybe I'll get Bertrand too. They'll want to know about this! :)

Comment: @chibacity: Tell Bernie I said "Hi!" and I'm still waiting on that $10 he owes me for dinner at Chotchkie's last Tuesday.

Comment: @klm9971 Eric thinks `overhiding` is the bomb, and Anders is still running around shouting "moar overhidingz". :)

Comment: omg, these comments interfere with some ICQ-channel.... did my router just broke down?

Comment: @klm9971 Bertrand says Eiffel had `overhiding` 50 years ago and hung up. :(